# No error when generic types doesn't match in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I wonder why I can provide different generic interface in `configure()` method than in my `class`? In the first `no error` example, I provide `IType<Args1>` as a generic type for `MyClass` and then I can simply override it by `IArgs2` that has a prop missing and I didn't get any error. Is it any way to ensure the types are exactly the same?

```js
interface IArgs1 {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface IArgs2 {
  a: string;
}

interface IArgs3 {
  d: string;
}

interface IType<T> {
  configure(args: T): void
}

// no error - even if 'b' is missing from IArgs2
class Class implements IType<IArgs1> {
  configure(args: IArgs2) {}
}

// error - because it's missing all IArgs1 attributes
class MyClass implements IType<IArgs1> {
  configure(args: IArgs3) {}
}
```

Comment: `configure(args: IArgs2)` won't fail if you'll pass it object with additional properties (other than `a`), but `configure(args: IArgs3)` will fail if you won't pass it `d`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `T` is in contravariant position.
Consider this example:

```js
interface IArgs1 {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface IArgs2 {
  a: string;
}

type Covariance<T> = { box: T };

declare let args1: Covariance<IArgs1>;
declare let args2: Covariance<IArgs2>;

args1 = args2 // error
args2 = args1 // ok
```

As you might have noticed `args2` is not assignable to `args1`. This is the opposite behavior.

Consider this example:

```js
type Contravariance<T> = { box: (value: T) => void };

declare let args1:  Contravariance<IArgs1>;
declare let args2:  Contravariance<IArgs2>;

args1 = args2 // ok
args2 = args1 // error
```

Now, inheritance arrow has changed in opposite way. `args1` is no more assignable to `args2` whereas `args2` is assignable to `args1`.

Same behavior you have in:

```js
interface IType<T> {
  configure(args: T): void
}
```

since `IType<T>` is the same as `Contravariance` in variance context.

This is why you don't have an error here:

```js
// no error - even if 'b' is missing from IArgs2
class Class implements IType<IArgs1> {
  configure(args: IArgs2) { }
}
```

because `IArgs1` extends `IArgs2`

You have an error here:

```js
// error - because it's missing all IArgs1 attributes
class MyClass implements IType<IArgs1> {
  configure(args: IArgs3) {}
}
```

because `IArgs1` and `IArgs3` are completely different types without any relation.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) you can find more about *-variance topic

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the class's intrinsic interface "comes first" and then all the `implements` constraints are checked against it afterward.

This means that, in the case of `MyClass`, the `configure(args: IArgs1): void` method signature (that originates from `implements IType<IArgs1>`) is checked against `configure(args: IArgs3): void` signature (that already exists in the class), Since `IArgs3` requires `IArgs1` to have the `d: string` property, this produces a conflict and **a compiler error**.

Conversely, in the case of `Class`, `IArgs2` (that already exists in the class) requires `IArgs1` (that comes from `implements IType<IArgs1>`) to have the `a: string` property, – which it has, and **thus no errors are produced**.

---

Not gonna lie, this is a bit of a surprise. I'd expect to first impose all `implements A, B, C` constraints on a class, and then fulfill them with actual class implementation, – but TypeScript isn't written by myself.