# Typescript: Type Error while using Record type

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

For following code (see [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMumFKAOYDc+hcAbnGHFOZdSPYwRAC2cYABsuVWg0LIQcQRAk8+MqAHtREAPxKp-ZAG0A1hACeu3gF1ycEKYYBfXLlCRYiFAGV2kHPuDoAJIgwGDAcKLAAF4QZMgARmoaELbShAEAggCuYAAWEODACGyx5InJqfpZmJxoNcgAPrJZoqKOzmCmAA4owaHhkTEZCGFqIMgAvH4ynT3kAOSBAHKBACqBGQAygQBaAKLzaQRdcKaianBxeDIymTn5hcWQceWalTeE1dDkGFhNIC02voHI4GLhZihNmoaKBhqNxlNroQIQtNgB5ADiy0O+hOZwuV30Mi+tV+UCONzueQKYSepQSSTeIApINwrPB3Uh0LUOThwDGk2myM5qMxaNQqxx7IhyAAShAYZRoHyBYj9CjkPNZXssZ5VntZTiZHjzpdyEiPiSfjUWaCOpzkCqEfomn0whFohAnS7kFCYSBvTImn6eWBA4QmvLFW4nWCEGNKMhcrZiJooOhyPL41BiAAebi0AA0yAAFJQSuRvCVi4h4eQnQBKSYAPmQVcgrbVMmWaw22325DLPkUbeHNZG-JA5DdA09jcrw5bQo+8ZAiYtH3S6Gy1MeJWIhaJm5JR4IDkFtcnADoTQSwZvkFAIGAslBxhuH1ev+XIIeH7dt3uGkin3P9-wIAIZw9GI4ioLIIDA8CTwfVkZAcRDfUxZZBx-Ed2wQ5BLzGcg-VhCcxgbBcSiXD9CFXddkBJZBzymIiQBvU5TWIe9NyfF832Xf8vyvXCMIfKkHlpfdyDghDTxuZDN1Qwh0P0dEMXFVYcOHKjIEo0dqImVsS1oghhNE+SJOAuk4ngURMDEz4anIAFWmBBsMO1XV9VlbSKwM39CPIqc5QVAIY2C-T8Jo+T6LAHBGPqFigvhDj8UuHiPj41933kmRzLHPKtx3SSQOeGSoHgxzLRqeTlLPNkwSAA)) of handler functions in an object I use the Record type:

```js
interface User {
    id: string;
    avatar: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    role?: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface State {
    isInitialized: boolean;
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: User | null;
}

type InitializeAction = {
    type: 'INITIALIZE';
    payload: {
        isAuthenticated: boolean;
        user: User | null;
    };
};

type LoginAction = {
    type: 'LOGIN';
    payload: {
        user: User;
        isAuthenticated: boolean;
    };
};

type LogoutAction = {
    type: 'LOGOUT';
};

type RegisterAction = {
    type: 'REGISTER';
    payload: {
        user: User;
    };
};

type Action =
    | InitializeAction
    | LoginAction
    | LogoutAction
    | RegisterAction;

const handlers: Record<string, (state: State, action: Action) => State> = {
    INITIALIZE: (state: State, action: InitializeAction): State => {
        const {
            isAuthenticated,
            user
        } = action.payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated,
            isInitialized: true,
            user
        };
    },
    LOGIN: (state: State, action: LoginAction): State => {
        const { user } = action.payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user
        };
    },
    LOGOUT: (state: State): State => ({
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null
    }),
    REGISTER: (state: State, action: RegisterAction): State => {
        const { user } = action.payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user
        };
    }
};
```

I do get following error for the handler functions though:

```
TS2322: Type '(state: State, action: InitializeAction) => State' is not assignable to type '(state: State, action: Action) => State'.   
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.     
    Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'InitializeAction'.       
      Type 'LoginAction' is not assignable to type 'InitializeAction'.         
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.           
          Type '"LOGIN"' is not assignable to type '"INITIALIZE"'.
```

Comment: Please, take a look at [the guide to type-safe Redux actions](https://itnext.io/forget-about-redux-boilerplate-now-it-is-just-one-little-hook-bd95a7a44d6f) I wrote a while ago, – might be worth the time

Comment: take a look at  [typescript union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) this is a common problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because of contravariance.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) you can find more information about this topic and how it works in typescript.

In order to type your `handler` object, you should use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
interface User {
    id: string;
    avatar: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    role?: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface State {
    isInitialized: boolean;
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: User | null;
}

type InitializeAction = {
    type: 'INITIALIZE';
    payload: {
        isAuthenticated: boolean;
        user: User | null;
    };
};

type LoginAction = {
    type: 'LOGIN';
    payload: {
        user: User;
        isAuthenticated: boolean;
    };
};

type LogoutAction = {
    type: 'LOGOUT';
};

type RegisterAction = {
    type: 'REGISTER';
    payload: {
        user: User;
    };
};

type Action =
    | InitializeAction
    | LoginAction
    | LogoutAction
    | RegisterAction;


// type Handlers = {
//     INITIALIZE: (state: State, action: InitializeAction) => State;
//     LOGIN: (state: State, action: LoginAction) => State;
//     LOGOUT: (state: State, action: LogoutAction) => State;
//     REGISTER: (state: State, action: RegisterAction) => State;
// }
type Handlers = {
    [Type in Action['type']]: (state: State, action: Extract<Action, { type: Type }>) => State
}


const handlers: Handlers = {
    INITIALIZE: (state, action) => {
        const {
            isAuthenticated,
            user
        } = action.payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated,
            isInitialized: true,
            user
        };
    },
    LOGIN: (state, action) => {
        const { user } = action.payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user
        };
    },
    LOGOUT: (state) => ({
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null
    }),
    REGISTER: (state, action) => {
        const { user } = action.payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user
        };
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBen4w)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883765/no-error-when-generic-types-doesnt-match-in-typescript/69884505#69884505) you can find related answer.

See this example:

```js
type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State;
const reducer: Reducer = (state, action) => state

type ContravariantReducer = Record<string, Reducer>

// Arrow of inheritance has changed in an opposite way
const contravariant: ContravariantReducer = {
    initialize: (state: State, action: InitializeAction) => state
}

// Arrow of inheritance has changed in an opposite way
const contravariant2: Record<string, (state: State, action: InitializeAction) => State> = {
    initialize: (state: State, action: Action) => state
}
```

P.S. Apart from typescript type issues, I strongly believe that you should type your reducer according to redux docs provided by **@Dima Parzhitsky**

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda dirty but it works:

```
const handlers: Record<string, (state: State, action: Action) => State> = {
    INITIALIZE: (state: State, action: Action): State => {
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = (action as InitializeAction).payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated,
            isInitialized: true,
            user,
        };
    },
    LOGIN: (state: State, action: Action): State => {
        const { user } = (action as LoginAction).payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user,
        };
    },
    LOGOUT: (state: State): State => ({
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null,
    }),
    REGISTER: (state: State, action: Action): State => {
        const { user } = (action as RegisterAction).payload;

        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user,
        };
    },
};
```